# Mosaicing non-overlapping rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, mosaic

I have a set of georeferenced rasters that I want to combine in a seamless layer in QGIS. I believe what I have to do is clip them by mask layer and then build a virtual raster. There is an issue however. The original maps that I have scanned have zero overlap, so each one starts exactly where the other one ends. What do you think would be the best course of action here:

- include the neatlines in the clipping mask - then my eventual map will have black lines along the seams
- exclude the neatlines - then there will be gaps up to 10 pixels wide - is there any good way to fill them?
- any other suggestions? maybe I am approaching it from entirely wrong angle?

By the way, is there by any chance a tool to trace the neatlines automatically instead of painstakingly drawing the clipping polygons manually?

Comment: Are you able to provide a graphic of what you are trying to achieve? Might help determine an answer for you.

Comment: You could fill the gaps of your "without neatlines" option with image inpainting.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude neatlines. You can fill nodata value with GDAL's 'fill nodata' tool. It will calculate values by interpolation. You can explore variables for interpolation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try two simple gdal tools: [gdaltindex](https://gdal.org/programs/gdaltindex.html) and [gdalbuildvrt](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html).

To create the mosaic, since your rasters are georreferenced, you just need:

```bsh
gdalbuildvrt mosaic.vrt *.tif
```

QGIS will open this `mosaic.vrt` raster.

If you want to create the grid around your rasters, you can use `gdaltindex`.

```bsh
gdaltindex mosaic.shp *.tif
```

Open both the `mosaic.vrt` and `mosaic.shp` in QGIS.

If the rasters are large, you may also need [gdaladdo](https://gdal.org/programs/gdaladdo.html) to create overviews of the raster. It will became much faster in QGIS.

```bsh
gdaladdo -ro mosaic.vrt
```

Comment: Thanks, this is valuable input, especially the overviews creation bit (because the rasters are, indeed, quite large). However my question was about slightly different issue. I am not sure **where** I should clip my rasters which were scanned from paper maps (before or after the neatlines) and if I could somehow automate the clipping process.